# Showing Model properties from Django on Admin

Tags: django

I have a model using the GeoIP library to render the country of the IP address for that record:

```
class PageIP(models.Model):
    """
    Detail of page
    """
    ip_address = models.IPAddressField(blank=True,verbose_name="IP Address")


    def _client_country(self):
        g = GeoIP()
        return g.country(self.ip_address)

    client_country = property(_client_country)
```

Is there any way to show this property (client_country) in the Django 1.1 admin?  As currently written, this doesn't appear in the admin.

Cheers.

Comment: Django says here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#ipaddressfield that The admin represents this as an <input type="text"> (a single-line input). So it should definately appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put it into the admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin 
admin.site.register(PageIP)
```

and it will appear there shortly. 
also, make sure your app is in settings.py under INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: The model is there, as is the field ip_address.

I need client_country in the admin though.

Comment: why not try __str__(self)? for writing into you should add a setter as well, not only getter.

Comment: great idea - that's so obvious I didn't think about it.  I'll use __unicode__(self) though.